# Java Script issue while submitting a form through JSP

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue when I am trying to submit a JSP page .

I will describe in short the scenario so that it would be clear.

**The Scenario**

I have some input elements made up in a html component  on JSP page.

The table has many `<tr>`. These `<tr>` have been given ids, for e.g. `<tr id="1">`.

Now I am trying to pass a comma separated list of these tr ids to server side code or Servlet.

The comma separated list is formed with looping some logic on submit of JSP or more specifically a form.

**The Problem:**

When I submit the form sometimes I do not receive the comma separated values mentioned above at server side code.

This happens occasionally. Now when I put some delay through Java Script like `setTimeOut()` I do not face the issue.

So can anyone please help me guiding on this?

Is Java Script behavior a bit non-sequential sometimes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the looping logic (which is presumably written in JS)?

Comment: "bit non - sequential sometimes ?" If request is submitted asynchronously yes. Post the relevant source code up ...

Comment: The request I am making to the server is not asynchronous.

Comment: "I am purposely not putting the code as it is proprietorial" - well then I don't think you can expect too much more help. A lot of us have the same constraints but still manage to post a cut-down version of our code that doesn't give away any trade secrets: you don't have to post the whole project. Surely you can at least provide (a) the `<form>` tag so we can see if/how you trap its `onsubmit` event; (b) the `<input type="submit">` button so we can see if/how you trap its `onclick`; (c) any onload/onready code that sets up your event handlers; (d) your comma-separated-list-making function.

Comment: For you information I am doing something like this.
<input type=image onClick="function_1();return false;" id="some_id"
               src="submit_button_image_path" border=0
               height=80 width=100 >
In function_1() there is a call to the function which make comma separated list.

Comment: So post your comma-separated-list-making function. Is such a generic concept really so secret? I've used the same type of code as what mdyang posted below and never had a problem that wasn't directly related to some bug in _my_ code. I find it easier to believe that there is something wrong in your code than that there is some mysterious intermittment timing issue with JavaScript itself.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript execution is sequential as long as you do NOT use asynchronous mechanism (e.g. Timer, Ajax, etc).
So the question is how you submitted the form. I've ever written code of similar function and I never encountered the problems you mentioned.

Here I provide my solution. Hope this can help.

I don't use a `<input type="submit" />` to submit my form. Instead, a common button is employed with an onclick event binding:

```
<form id="form1" action="serverscripturl" method="post">
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="form1submit()" />
  <input id="field1" name="field1" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Then I use a JavaScript function to perform the concatenation and submission:

```
function form1submit(){
  var list = ""; // your comma separated list
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++)
    list += (data[i]+",");
  // set the value of field1 the list
  document.getElementById("field1").value = list;
  document.getElementById("form1").submit(); // submit the form<br>
}
```

and on server side script like `response.getParameter("field1")` will work.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This is exactly the same way I am doing it. And also on serer side I do the same response.getParameter("field1"). But as I said earlier I still face an issue sometimes the comma separated listed been sent as empty. And I also do no see any Java Script error.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is solved as you added submission delay? Did you use anything async (e.g. ajax) that requires callback to handle finishing? Do you know where the problem actually occurred? You can do a number of things to spot the location. e.g. alert() the string before form submission happens to see if concatenation succeeded 2) capture the HTTP datagram to see if all needed data are correctly sent. Maybe you can post your issue-related code to help diagnose.

Comment: I tried using HTTP Live Headers and also I could see in the Firebug of Mozilla that post parameter went blank. and when I put an alert everything works fine. In this case I feel alert is a event waiting for user response so again considerable lag is present for the comma separated list to form. I am purposely not putting the code as it is proprietorial . But I can say surely that whatever you have shown above in the code is same what I am trying.

Comment: Did you try alert(list) immediately after concatenation finishes? anything displayed?

Comment: When there is an alert placed list is formed properly or as expected. But the moment I remove alert issue persists. That is what I am trying to pin point earlier.

Comment: @user769462 - when you say the parameter "goes blank", are you saying the parameter does exist but contains an empty string, or the parameter doesn't exist at all?

Comment: parameter exists but contains empty string